# How to pass (date) object to Ember handlebars helper?

Tags: ember.js, handlebars.js

How can I access a passed object in an Ember Handlebars helper?

Inside the helper 'date' is always undefined.

```
// date object
var date = new Date('2013-05-10T01:55:00+01:00');

// helper
Ember.Handlebars.makeBoundHelper('format', function(date) {
     return moment(date).format();
};

// template
{{format date}}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use `registerBoundHelper` not `makeBoundHelper`. `makeBoundHelper` doesn't take the helper name

```
// date object
var date = new Date('2013-05-10T01:55:00+01:00');

// helper
Ember.Handlebars.registerBoundHelper('format', function(date) {
     return moment(date).format()
};
```

Comment: You're right, it has to be registerBoundHelper. However, in the helper 'date' is still undefined.

Comment: It's now working. I was testing it with qUnit and didn't add the date object to a controller but immediately passed it in the helper, which was wrong. Thank you!

Comment: `ember generate helper` now uses makeBoundHelper, despite the docs indicating makeBoundHelper is deprecated. What's the deal?